# D3 Tree update color of nodes dynamically

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, tree

So I'm trying to create a tree in D3 (Adapted from [here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083)) to show a series of nodes that are a specific color according to their value. The problem is that I am getting new data at set intervals that may change these values. I want the tree to update the colors accordingly when it recieves new information. I've tried a number of different methods that result in the entire tree redrawing itself, flying onto the screen, and auto expanding every nodes children. The desired effect that I am looking for is for the color of updated nodes to change, while the tree respects the status of collapsed/uncollapsed nodes that the user doesn't see the whole tree reset itself. Is this possible?

Here's what i have so far:

```js
// Get JSON data

var treeData = {
  "name": "rootAlert",
  "alert": "true",
  "children": [{
    "name": "Child1",
    "alert": "true",
    "children": [{
      "name": "Child1-1",
      "alert": "false"
    }, {
      "name": "Child1-2",
      "alert": "false"
    }, {
      "name": "Child1-3",
      "alert": "true"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Child2",
    "alert": "false",
    "children": [{
      "name": "Child2-1",
      "alert": "false"
    }, {
      "name": "Child2-2",
      "alert": "false"
    }, {
      "name": "Child2-3",
      "alert": "false"
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Child3",
    "alert": "false"
  }]
}






// Calculate total nodes, max label length
var totalNodes = 0;
var maxLabelLength = 0;
// variables for drag/drop
var selectedNode = null;
var draggingNode = null;
// panning variables
var panSpeed = 200;
var panBoundary = 20; // Within 20px from edges will pan when dragging.
// Misc. variables
var i = 0;
var duration = 750;
var root;

// size of the diagram
var viewerWidth = $(document).width();
var viewerHeight = $(document).height();

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
  .size([viewerHeight, viewerWidth]);

// define a d3 diagonal projection for use by the node paths later on.
var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
  .projection(function(d) {
    return [d.y, d.x];
  });

// A recursive helper function for performing some setup by walking through all nodes

function visit(parent, visitFn, childrenFn) {
  if (!parent) return;

  visitFn(parent);

  var children = childrenFn(parent);
  if (children) {
    var count = children.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      visit(children[i], visitFn, childrenFn);
    }
  }
}

function visit2(parent, visitFn, childrenFn) {
  if (!parent) return;

  visitFn(parent);

  var children = childrenFn(parent);
  if (children) {
    var count = children.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      visit(children[i], visitFn, childrenFn);
    }
  }
}

// Call visit function to establish maxLabelLength
visit(treeData, function(d) {
  totalNodes++;
  maxLabelLength = Math.max(d.name.length, maxLabelLength);

}, function(d) {
  return d.children && d.children.length > 0 ? d.children : null;
});

// TODO: Pan function, can be better implemented.

function pan(domNode, direction) {
  var speed = panSpeed;
  if (panTimer) {
    clearTimeout(panTimer);
    translateCoords = d3.transform(svgGroup.attr("transform"));
    if (direction == 'left' || direction == 'right') {
      translateX = direction == 'left' ? translateCoords.translate[0] + speed : translateCoords.translate[0] - speed;
      translateY = translateCoords.translate[1];
    } else if (direction == 'up' || direction == 'down') {
      translateX = translateCoords.translate[0];
      translateY = direction == 'up' ? translateCoords.translate[1] + speed : translateCoords.translate[1] - speed;
    }
    scaleX = translateCoords.scale[0];
    scaleY = translateCoords.scale[1];
    scale = zoomListener.scale();
    svgGroup.transition().attr("transform", "translate(" + translateX + "," + translateY + ")scale(" + scale + ")");
    d3.select(domNode).select('g.node').attr("transform", "translate(" + translateX + "," + translateY + ")");
    zoomListener.scale(zoomListener.scale());
    zoomListener.translate([translateX, translateY]);
    panTimer = setTimeout(function() {
      pan(domNode, speed, direction);
    }, 50);
  }
}

// Define the zoom function for the zoomable tree

function zoom() {
  svgGroup.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}


// define the zoomListener which calls the zoom function on the "zoom" event constrained within the scaleExtents
var zoomListener = d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([0.1, 3]).on("zoom", zoom);

// define the baseSvg, attaching a class for styling and the zoomListener
var baseSvg = d3.select("#tree-container").append("svg")
  .attr("width", viewerWidth)
  .attr("height", viewerHeight)
  .attr("class", "overlay")
  .call(zoomListener);


// Function to center node when clicked/dropped so node doesn't get lost when collapsing/moving with large amount of children.

function centerNode(source) {
  scale = zoomListener.scale();
  x = -source.y0;
  y = -source.x0;
  x = x * scale + viewerWidth / 2;
  y = y * scale + viewerHeight / 2;
  d3.select('g').transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")scale(" + scale + ")");
  zoomListener.scale(scale);
  zoomListener.translate([x, y]);
}

function leftAlignNode(source) {
  scale = zoomListener.scale();
  x = -source.y0;
  y = -source.x0;
  x = (x * scale) + 100;
  y = y * scale + viewerHeight / 2;
  d3.select('g').transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")scale(" + scale + ")");
  zoomListener.scale(scale);
  zoomListener.translate([x, y]);
}

// Toggle children function

function toggleChildren(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else if (d._children) {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  return d;
}

function toggle(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
}

// Toggle children on click.

function click(d) {
  if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) return; // click suppressed

  if (d._children != null) {
    var isCollapsed = true
  } else {
    var isCollapsed = false;
  }

  d = toggleChildren(d);
  update(d);

  if (isCollapsed) {
    leftAlignNode(d);
  } else {
    centerNode(d);
  }

}

function update(source) {
  // Compute the new height, function counts total children of root node and sets tree height accordingly.
  // This prevents the layout looking squashed when new nodes are made visible or looking sparse when nodes are removed
  // This makes the layout more consistent.
  var levelWidth = [1];
  var childCount = function(level, n) {

    if (n.children && n.children.length > 0) {
      if (levelWidth.length <= level + 1) levelWidth.push(0);

      levelWidth[level + 1] += n.children.length;
      n.children.forEach(function(d) {
        childCount(level + 1, d);
      });
    }
  };
  childCount(0, root);
  var newHeight = d3.max(levelWidth) * 25; // 25 pixels per line
  tree = tree.size([newHeight, viewerWidth]);

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
    links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Set widths between levels based on maxLabelLength.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.y = (d.depth * (maxLabelLength * 5)); //maxLabelLength * 10px
    // alternatively to keep a fixed scale one can set a fixed depth per level
    // Normalize for fixed-depth by commenting out below line
    // d.y = (d.depth * 500); //500px per level.
  });

  // Update the nodes…
  node = svgGroup.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(nodes, function(d) {
      return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
    });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
    //.call(dragListener)
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
    })
    .on('click', click);

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
    .attr('class', 'nodeCircle')
    .attr("r", 0)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    });

  nodeEnter.append("text")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10;
    })
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr('class', 'nodeText')
    .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
      return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
    })
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    })
    .style("fill-opacity", 0);


  // Update the text to reflect whether node has children or not.
  node.select('text')
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10;
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
      return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
    })
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    });

  // Change the circle fill depending on whether it has children and is collapsed
  node.select("circle.nodeCircle")
    .attr("r", 4.5)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    });

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
    });
  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
    .attr("r", 4.5)
    .style("fill", function(d) { // alert(d.alert);
      //console.log(d.name + ' is ' + d.alert)
      if (d.alert == 'true') //if alert == true
        return "red";
      else return d._children ? "green" : "green";
    });

  // Fade the text in
  nodeUpdate.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
    })
    .remove();

  nodeExit.select("circle")
    .attr("r", 0);

  nodeExit.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 0);

  // Update the links…
  var link = svgGroup.selectAll("path.link")
    .data(links, function(d) {
      return d.target.id;
    });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x0,
        y: source.y0
      };
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x,
        y: source.y
      };
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    })
    .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}

// Append a group which holds all nodes and which the zoom Listener can act upon.
var svgGroup = baseSvg.append("g");

// Define the root
root = treeData;
root.x0 = viewerHeight / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

// Layout the tree initially and center on the root node.
tree.nodes(root).forEach(function(n) {
  toggle(n);
});
update(root);
leftAlignNode(root);


setInterval(function() {
  //update the color of each node
}, 2000);
```

```css
.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.overlay {
  background-color: #EEE;
}

.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: gray;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.templink {
  fill: none;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

.ghostCircle.show {
  display: block;
}

.ghostCircle,
.activeDrag .ghostCircle {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="tree-container"></div>
```

I've found a great example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/1ggGsQ8FjApvNcdpzTOs?p=preview)

It does basically exactly what I want. However, instead of updating the tree when a selection is made, I want it to update automatically when new data is recieved. I'd also like to see it not in AngularJS. I've attempted to implement the same type of update function from that example, but mine still pos in from the top left, while the example is so smooth!

Answer (score 0):

It may be best to re-render the visualization when your data pipeline is updated.

You'll have to save the state of your visualization, preserving all information that will be needed to re-render the visualization, so that your users are none the wiser.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm looking to do. I included an example of this working in the original post, but I cannot seem to replicate it on my own. I have implemented most of the changes that the example has (minus the angular stuff) and it still pops and redraws the whole thing